# Berkeley-db-je dbverify tool slow

Tags: java, corruption, berkeley-db-je

So I'm using the bdb je dbverify to check for corruption in a large bdb database around 250GB.
Below is the command I'm using to run the tool and its taking quite a long time. Estimated 8 or 9 hours.

```
java -cp je-4.1.17.jar com.sleepycat.je.util.DbVerify -h /mydatabase
```

I tired a smaller bdb around 2.5GB and it took 6 minutes which when scaled by 100 works out to be around 10 hours. Is there any way I can speed this up? Settings or what not?

Source code for the dbverify tool is [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/berkeleydb/je/2.0.83/com/sleepycat/je/util/DbVerify.java), it doesn't seem to provide for any other options to do a faster check.

Comment: My first port of call would be to increase heap size by adding a `-Xmx` option to the command line.